# Link to member variable is incorrect

Tags: c++, member-variables

**Problem overview:** A member variable is correctly set in the setter but read from a wrong address in the getter.

**Project set up:** I am using a microcontroller of the STM32F4 series. The project contains C- and C++-code. The latter is used for a GUI which is made with TouchGFX. I use the compiler of Keil 5.29.0.0.

**Problem details:** There is a class with a lot of data (the Model class in TouchGFX). In this class, the following happened several times: I added a new private member variable to the class and initialized it in the initializer list of the constructor. I created the simplest version of getter and setter, i.e. setting the value given by the parameter resp. returning the member variable, without any checks or error handling. Then I ran the system and did not get the expected value on the GUI. Stepping through with the debugger showed that the setter and the getter were linked to different memory adresses: The setter wrote to an address in the RAM (as expected), but the getter read from an address in the flash which had nothing to do with the class.

Code example:

Model.hpp:

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model();

    void bind(ModelListener* listener)
    {
        modelListener = listener;
    }

    void tick();
    
    /* Several getters and setters... */
    
    uint8_t getTheProblematicVariable();
    void setTheProblematicVariable(uint8_t theVariable);
    
    protected:
    ModelListener* modelListener;

    private:
    /* Several variables */
    
    uint8_t theProblematicVariable;
};
```

Model.cpp:

```
Model::Model() 
: modelListener(0),
  /* Several variables */
  theProblematicVariable(90)
{}

/* ... Implementation of the getters and setters of all other variables */

uint8_t getTheProblematicVariable()
{
    return theProblematicVariable;
}

void setTheProblematicVariable(uint8_t theVariable)
{
    theProblematicVariable = theVariable;
}
```

**Trial and error:**

- Moving the variable around, i.e. changing its position in the list of the member variables (and in the initializer list) changed the address from which the getter read but it was still an address in the flash.
- Clean and rebuild did not fix it.
- Declaring the member variable as static solves the problem, but that is more lika a workaround than a solution because I don't understand what is going wrong.

**Internet search:**

- It is not about dynamically allocated elements as here: [Pointer pointing to wrong address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405614/pointer-pointing-to-wrong-address)
- The problem is not the same as here: [C++ "Getter" method throwing access violation when trying to return private variable in same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522615/c-getter-method-throwing-access-violation-when-trying-to-return-private-vari)
- A comment to this problem ([C++ calling completely wrong (virtual) method of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798966/c-calling-completely-wrong-virtual-method-of-an-object)) talks about the vtable and linking which sounds interesting but the solution was about casting and subclasses which is not applicable to my problem.
- As there are no virtual functions called in the constructor, it is not the same problem as here: [Getter returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796407/getter-returns-wrong-value). But the author's suggestion: "Second possible explanation is that due to some problem with project's Makefile, one of the source files was compiled against different libraries and there was some conflict when linking them together, maybe a memory collision." might apply to my problem. But I do not know how to check that.

**Question:** Where should I look deeper to find the problem?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: You provide details, including your thoughts and research, my compliments. But (as mentioned above) it is very risky to guess where the problem is in code, when you did not find it (which is why you ask here). A tested method to avoid leaving out the relevant code part is the MRE (as linked above). Please try to provide one. In case of special (embedded) environments, it does not mean to provide something which we can copy paste into our (different) environment. The target ist to enable some theoretical user who does have that environment. Others then can still read guaranteed relevant code.

Comment: One would have thought that given *The setter wrote to an address in the RAM (as expected), but the getter read from an address in the flash which had nothing to do with the class* code for the getter and the setter should immediately follow.

Comment: Do you hand the `Model` object to the GUI by copy? That could make the setter (on object A) and the getter (on object B) refer to different memory locations.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything wrong with *The setter wrote to an address in the RAM (as expected), but the getter read from an address in the flash...* Your code exists in FLASH (that's where it goes when you flash the program to the STM). The fact that the `getter()` is loading from flash while the `setter()` is writing to RAM doesn't strike me as odd. I don't 'have a STM to lookup the flash/memory mappings on, but were I you, I would confirm whether or not there is a fixed mapping to a section of RAM that is accessed as a pseudo stack, etc..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  @Yunnosch I will try to create an example next week, but I assume that I will not succeed. It is part of the problem that it is not easily reproducible on purpose.

Comment: @n. m. I added the getter and setter of the variable. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Frodyne As far as I can see, the model is always handed over by reference, never as a copy. This is part of the code generated by TouchGFX so unfortunately I cannot look into everything.

Comment: @David  I don't understand why you do not find it odd. A variable that is created at runtime should be in the RAM and no matter which function uses it, the address behind the variable should always be the same, shouldn't it? I'm talking about the address of the variable, not the addresses of the functions.

Comment: If your class member is at an unexpected address, check the value of `this`.

Comment: @Ardian you have to look at your lower level flash setup and flash script. Like I said, I don't have a STM, but  in my experience your flash setup generally does two things. It maps your program into flash and maps flash registers and library functions into that flash memory (the registers and functions into two independent regions). The register mapping also allows mapping an area of flash as RAM. Your datasheet will layout that mapping in grueling detail. That's why I indicated you will need to consult your documentation to answer that question.

Comment: @n. m. `this` in the setter points to an address in the RAM, close to the address where the member variable is stored. `this` in the getter points to an address in the flash, close to where the member variable is read from. Thus, the addresses are consistent within each function. But the address range of `this` and the member variable in the getter function is occupied by other stuff as the map file says: NMI_Handler/stm32f4xx_it.o, a power supply test... If both would point to regions in the RAM, I would expect that there are two instances of Model, but no instance should be in the flash.

Comment: @David Ah, thanks, now I understand. But no region of the flash is used as RAM.

Comment: So the getter gets an incorrect `this`. It is impossible to determine why given the information supplied. You probably want to use the debugger and trace it back through the call stack.